# To find the difference in columns of data with respect to unique columns in java

Tags: java, collections

I have  a scenario where 2 lists are to be compared with 1st column being present in both the lists as unique ID and that difference in rest of the columns for corresponding ID's needs to be fetched.

> E.g
>
> List 1
>   Apple    12 1
>   Windows  12 3 5
>
> List 2
>   Apple    12 1 4
>   Windows  12 3 5
>
> Output:
>   Apple 4

Comment: I tried the below code but doesnt work,   Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>(List1);
   Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>(List2);
   s2.removeAll(s1);  
   diff = new ArrayList<>(s2);
  }
  return diff;    This returns Apple 12 1 4 but I only need Apple 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added comments. Check below code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class AddTwoArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1.add("Windows 12 3 5");
        list1.add("Apple 12 1");
        list1.add("Orange");
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2.add("Apple 4 12 1");
        list2.add("Orange 5");
        list2.add("Windows");

        TreeSet s1 = new TreeSet<String>(list1);
        TreeSet s2 = new TreeSet<String>(list2);
        TreeSet s3 = new TreeSet<String>(list1);
        TreeSet s4 = new TreeSet<String>(list2);
        s1.removeAll(s2);
        s4.removeAll(s3);
        List<String> diff = new ArrayList<String>(s1);
        List<String> diff1 = new ArrayList<String>(s4);

        List<String> diffArray = null;
        for (int tmp = 0 ; tmp < diff.size(); tmp++) {
            diffArray = findDiff(diff.get(tmp).split(" "), diff1.get(tmp).split(" ")); // call method findDiff

            if(diffArray != null){
                for(String tmp1: diffArray){
                    String[] diffSplit = tmp1.split(" ");
                    for(int i =0; i < diffSplit.length; i++){
                        System.out.print(diffSplit[i] + " ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static List<String> findDiff(String[] diff, String[] diff1) { // find the different between two arrays
        HashSet<String> map = new HashSet<String>();
        List<String> diffArray = new ArrayList<String>();
        diffArray.add(diff[0]); // add unique key
        for (String i : diff){
            map.add(i);
        }
        for (String i : diff1) {
            if (!map.contains(i)){ //find different element between diff and diff1 
                diffArray.add(i);
            } 
        }

        map = new HashSet<String>();

        for (String i : diff1)
            map.add(i);
        for (String i : diff) {
            if (!map.contains(i)){   //find different element between diff1 and diff
                diffArray.add(i);
            } 
        }
        return diffArray; //diff array
    }
}
```

If you are not clear comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works well but to suit it to my application I need to print the output to a file like the this :    FileUtil.writeToFile(diff, outputPath + "\\TestData\\" + outputFileName, false); Hence I need to return the diff back to a function which is of type ArrayList<String> but the diff you have made computations to is of type String. Could you please help me resolve this?

Comment: @Sindhu You can put both the lists (diff, diff1) inside the map and return the map to other function. Make the other function return type as map. Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
  map.put("FirstList", diff);
  map.put("FirstList", diff1);

Comment: @Sindhu I have changed the code, please check. There are few cases i didnt check. Hope you can modify those.

Answer (score 0):

For ex

```
  ArrayList l1=new ArrayList();

    l1.add("a");

    l1.add("b");

    l1.add("c");

    l1.add("d");

    l1.add("e");

    l1.add("f");

    ArrayList l12=new ArrayList();
    l12.add("z");
    l12.add("b");
    l12.add("c");
    l12.add("d");
    l12.add("e");
    l12.add("g");


ArrayList outList = new ArrayList();


for(int i=1 ;i<l12.size(); i++)

 {

        if(!(l1.contains(l12.get(i))))
        {
            outList.add(l12.get(i));


        }
    }
```

Here outList contains element which are difference between 2 list but excluding 1st value of the list l1 and l12.

Comment: Thanks but I need to know with respect to which system the value of other columns have changed, so I need Apple also to be displayed.

Comment: So add that element Apple to the outList before adding the difference element into it